# Process a large file using Apache Airflow Task Groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

I need to process a zip file(that contains a text file) using task groups in airflow. No. of lines can vary from 1 to 50 Million. I want to read the text file in the zip file process each line and write the processed line to another text file, zip it, update Postgres tables and call another DAG to transmit this new zip file to an SFTP server.

Since a single task can take more time to process a file with millions of lines, I would like to process the file using a task group. That is, a single task in the task group can process certain no. of lines and transform them. For ex. if we receive a file with 15 Million lines, 6 task groups can be called to process 2.5 Million lines each.

But I am confused how to make the task group dynamic and pass the offset to each task.
Below is a sample that I tried with fixed offset in islice(),

```
def start_task(**context):
    print("starting the Main task...")


def apply_transformation(line):
    return f"{line}_NEW"


def task1(**context):
    data = context['dag_run'].conf
    file_name = data.get("file_name")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name), encoding="UTF-8") as fp:
                for record in islice(fp, 1, 2000000):
                    apply_transformation(record)


def task2(**context):
    data = context['dag_run'].conf
    file_name = data.get("file_name")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name), encoding="UTF-8") as fp:
                for record in islice(fp, 2000001, 4000000):
                    apply_transformation(record)


def task3(**context):
    data = context['dag_run'].conf
    file_name = data.get("file_name")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name), encoding="UTF-8") as fp:
                for record in islice(fp, 4000001, 6000000):
                    apply_transformation(record)


def task4(**context):
    data = context['dag_run'].conf
    file_name = data.get("file_name")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name), encoding="UTF-8") as fp:
                for record in islice(fp, 6000001, 8000000):
                    apply_transformation(record)


def task5(**context):
    data = context['dag_run'].conf
    file_name = data.get("file_name")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name), encoding="UTF-8") as fp:
                for record in islice(fp, 8000001, 10000000):
                    apply_transformation(record)


def final_task(**context):
    print("This is the final task to update postgres tables and call SFTP DAG...")


with DAG("main",
         schedule_interval=None,
         default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    st = PythonOperator(
        task_id='start_task',
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=start_task
    )

    with TaskGroup(group_id='task_group_1') as tg1:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='task1',
            python_callable=task1,
            dag=dag,
        )

        t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='task2',
            python_callable=task2,
            dag=dag,
        )

        t3 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='task3',
            python_callable=task3,
            dag=dag,
        )

        t4 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='task4',
            python_callable=task4,
            dag=dag,
        )

        t5 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='task5',
            python_callable=task5,
            dag=dag,
        )

    ft = PythonOperator(
        task_id='final_task',
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=final_task
    )

    st >> tg1 >> ft
```

After applying transformation to each line, I want to get these transformed lines from different tasks and merge them into a new file and do rest of the operations in the `final_task`.

Or are there any other methods to process large files with millions of lines in parallel?

Comment: I have one question what executor are you using? In any case, I do not recommend to run large calculation process in airflow even if they are in separate task. You would rather prefer to use a parallel framework such as dask or pyspark to do the job and lunch the job from airflow. In any case if you still what ot use airflow I can add an answer on how to declare dynamic tasks

Comment: Note also lastest recommendations from aiflow recommend task decorator over pythonoperator

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte I am using Celery Executor.

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Oh. I saw Dask when I googled. So is it better to use Dask instead of taskgroup in airflow?

Comment: In such a case I would really recommend to run en entire job using a parallel framework or using threads, it can be great if you do that inside a container. Since pods in celery or kubernetes executor do not share information and merging the data back can be tricky.

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte I would be nice if you can you provide an ex. to process file using taskgroup?

Comment: definitively, Dask is a great tool and very easy to use, Airflow should be use to organize task and schedule them but not to split a task into several to parallelize it

Comment: Also, one issue you might encounter is file locking when trying to read from the same file. Is just the processing slow or is the read operation slow as well? If it is "just" the processing you could read the file in the start, create multiple "chunks" (files) and then let each task read its individual chunk writing back the processed data. Finally you merge the chunks into one processed file and delete the chunks after finishing the merge.